# Parsing Out all HTML Tags/Non-text; Java

Tags: java, regex, html-parsing, jsoup

What is the best way to take html from a webpage, strip all of the HTML tags/javascript code/ anything that's not text to be displayed, and finally be able to return this information with some separators for every piece of text that was wrapped in a different html tag?

First I tried using JSOUP:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page").get();
String html = doc.body().text();
```

This is good for taking out all the non-text but doesn't return me any sort of division.

I'm currently trying to use regex like:

```
html.replaceAll("\\<.*?\\>", "")
```

But I'm really not familiar with regex, and I have problems taking out javascript. This method however does have newlines that I can use to track down seperate text groups from different tag wrappings.

I was just wondering if there was some easy way of doing this before I try more regex to get it to work.

Thanks

Comment: Oops, sorry about my post. Wasn't even paying attention. Must be too late for me.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "any sort of division"? What output format exactly are you expecting? Do you mean something which is accomplished by inserting two `\r\n` after every `<p></p>` and one after every `<br/>` or something? Or did you expect an ASCII art representation of a HTML page?

Comment: That could work. The first thing about inserting \r\n that is.

Comment: html.replaceAll("(\<script\s?.*?\>(.|\r\n)+?\<\/(no)?script\>)","");

Comment: OK, just do it. Next time, whenever you consider for a second to use regex to parse HTML, [read this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html).

Comment: I tried String html = doc.toString(); html.replaceAll("(\\<script\\s?.*?\\>(.|\\r\\n)+?\\<\\/(no)?script\\>)","");       System.out.println(html); Doesn't seem to work. SOrry I'm not very good with regex am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like jsoup doesn't provide an immediately obvious way to do that, so I made a quick hack by editing the source code and adding the method `text_mod()` to `Element`. There are limitations to this approach, but if you find it useful, you can download the modified jar at http://ge.tt/9PAMpzA.

Here's the addition:

```
public String text_mod(){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    text_mod(sb);
    return sb.toString().trim().replaceAll("\n+", "\n");
}

private void text_mod(StringBuilder accum) {
    appendWhitespaceIfBr(this, accum);

    for (Node child : childNodes) {
        if (child instanceof TextNode) {
            TextNode textNode = (TextNode) child;
            appendNormalisedText(accum, textNode);
        } else if (child instanceof Element) {
            Element element = (Element) child;
    //        if (accum.length() > 0 && element.isBlock() && !TextNode.lastCharIsWhitespace(accum))
    //            accum.append("\n");
            element.text_mod(accum);
        }
        accum.append("\n");
    }
}
```

For example, try this:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String html = "<html><head><title>HTML</title></head>"
              + "<body><p>Paragraph 1.</p><p>Paragraph 2.</p></body></html>";
        System.out.println(Jsoup.parse(html).body().text_mod());
    }
}
```

I get

```
Paragraph 1.
Paragraph 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

Regexes will generally not work for arbitrary HTML, since Regular Expressions can't fully parse HTML (The technical reason is called the Pumping Lemma, which isn't important for the task at hand).

I would recommend starting with an XML parser (assuming your HTML doesn't do anything too weird) and looking down the parse tree for data that goes in displayable tags. XPath expressions would be pretty helpful here.

Comment: While true, you are not really answering the concrete question. Just post a comment. Note that OP has mentioned Jsoup which is a *way much better* way than XPath.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript with the DOM you can get the text of any HTML element with the `textContent` or `innerText` properties of the DOM element. If you do this for the BODY element, you have a "text" version of the page.

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
var bodyText = body.textContent || body.innerText;
```